# If condition in array to show data in the table

Tags: php, arrays, pdo

I have a dropdown list contains "Processed","Unreleased","Paid", that are from the Status Column. I want to add the Scanned Copy in the option but that is from the other column Scanned copy.  What will Im going to do to make it work? Here's my code.

```
$searchstat = (!empty($_REQUEST['optstat']) ? $_REQUEST['optstat'] : '%');
$vartxtsummryNo = (!empty($_REQUEST['txtsummryNo']) ?   $_REQUEST['txtsummryNo'] : '%');

if($searchstat!="%"){
  $vartxtsummryNo="%";
}

$sc=ScanCopy();
$scan_copy=array("Scanned Copy");
$astatus = array("Processed","Unreleased","Paid");
$astatus = array_merge($astatus, $scan_copy);

if ($astatus[$scan_copy]) { $sc; }

foreach ($astatus as $stat){

$optstatus  .= "<option " . ($searchstat  ==  $stat ? "selected" : "") . ">$stat</option>";
}
```

This is the query for fetching data when Scanned copy is selected.

```
function ScanCopy() {

  $sql2="SELECT * FROM payment_summary_log WHERE Scanned_copy IS NOT NULL ORDER BY Date_Created";
  $mesconn = dbConnect();
  $messtmt1 = $mesconn->prepare($sql2);
  $data = $messtmt1->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  $mesconn=null;  
  return $data;
}
```

Here's the structure of search box and the dropdownlist.

```
echo "<form method=get name='" . $_REQUEST['option'] . ".form' autocomplete='off'>";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='option' value='" . $_REQUEST['option'] . "'>";
echo "<table class=normal2 style='font-size:0.6em;'>";
echo "<h2 style='color:blue'>Payment Summary Tracking</h2><hr>";

echo "<tr><th>Payment Summary No. :</th><td colspan=2><input type=text name='txtsummryNo' value='".$vartxtsummryNo."'> <input type=submit name='bnt_setdate' value='Find'></td>";
echo "<tr><th>Status :</th><td colspan=2><select name=optstat onchange='document.forms[\"" .$_REQUEST['option'] . ".form\"].submit();'>$optstatus</select></td></tr>";
echo "</tr></table></form>";
echo "<h2></h2><hr>";
```

Answer (score 0):

1. First you need to return a valid `$data` from `ScanCopy()` function, which is not happening currently
2. Second You need to merge the return from scancopy function to `$astatus` array and add it to the dropdown :

   ```
    $astatus = array_merge($astatus, $scan);
   ```

Please modify the array accordingly before merging, I just provided you the hint, for more details look below:

> http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Comment: Can you please help me to do it?

Comment: which part you need help with ?

Comment: I updated my codes. please look at it. Is it right? but still no data are displayed

Comment: I am not sure what you are doing here : if ($astatus[$scan_copy]) { $sc; } , can you please calrify ?

Comment: When Scanned Copy is selected I want to display the data from my query "SELECT * FROM payment_summary_log WHERE Scanned_copy IS NOT NULL ORDER BY Date_Created";

Comment: I am sorry but it is still not clear, what is the structure of your dropdown html ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96849/discussion-between-thepiyush13-and-kimlyn-tormes).